# Trigger Duplicate CSV

Tags: apex, csv, upload

I am trying to upload a CSV file / insert a bulk of records using the import wizard. In short I would like to keep the latest record, in case if duplicates are found.
Duplicates record are a combination of First name, Last name and title

For example if my CSV file looks like the following:

James,Wistler,34,New York,Married
James,Wistler,34,London,Married
....
....
James,Wistler,34,New York,Divorced

This should only keep in my org:  **James,Wistler,34,New York,Divorced**

I have been trying to write a trigger before an update / insert but so far no success
Here is my trigger code:
(The code is not yet finished (only filering with Firstname), I am having a problem deleting found duplicate in my CSV )
Any hints.
Thanks for reading!

```
trigger CheckDuplicateInsert on Customer__c(before insert,before update){

Map <String, Customer__c> customerFirstName = new Map<String,Customer__c>();
list <Customer__c> CustomerList = Trigger.new;


for (Customer__c newCustomer : CustomerList)
{
    if ((newCustomer.First_Name__c != null && newCustomer.Last_Name__c!= null &&  newCustomer.Title__c!= null ) && System.Trigger.isInsert )
    {
        if (customerFirstName.containsKey(newCustomer.First_Name__c) )
        {
            delete customerFirstName.get(newCustomer.First_Name__c);
        }
        else
        {
            customerFirstName.put(newCustomer.First_Name__c , newCustomer);

        }
    }
    else if ((System.Trigger.oldMap.get(newCustomer.id)!= null)&&newCustomer.First_Name__c != System.Trigger.oldMap.get(newCustomer.id).First_Name__c )
    {
            newCustomer.First_Name__c=newCustomer.First_Name__c+'UPDATED';
            customerFirstName.put(newCustomer.First_Name__c , newCustomer);
        }

}

for (Customer__c customer : [SELECT First_Name__c FROM Customer__c WHERE First_Name__c IN :customerFirstName.KeySet()])
{
    if (customer.First_Name__c!=null){
    Customer__c newCustomer=customerFirstName.get(customer.First_Name__c);
    newCustomer.First_Name__c=Customer.First_Name__c+'EXIST_DB';
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: Any reason you don't de-dupe before uploading? It might be easier.

Comment: In my Customer__c there is the priority field. If duplicates are found I need to delete the old and insert the new one but update the priority with the highest value. + this is a kind of challenge / assignment I am requested to do.

Comment: The person who set you this challenge/assignment are they ok with you getting help? I would assume they want you to solve it yourself

Comment: As per http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/280/ideas-on-cross-posting-policy I believe this question feels more "at home" on general StackOverflow (the solution might be to "just use Excel to de-dupe them"). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504543/trigger-duplicate-csv

Comment: Hi Daniel, I have not asked anyone to solve it for me. I am asking just for guidance :) I am also going to let them know about this thread. And to be honest, it is killing me to know what is wrong, this has turned to be a personal challenge :)

Comment: You said that " I am having a problem deleting found duplicate in my CSV", but it's hard for me to figure out what the problem is.  Could you please specify exactly what's going wrong? That is: what error message and stacktrace are you getting?  Or, with some sample data, what is your expected result vs. what actually happens?

Comment: I think you'll discover that this task will be easier if you have an external Id assigned to your data before you import it via CSV. You'll find it convenient for creating a map of all the records you're trying to insert and creating a query so you can compare them to the ones that already exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial requirement can easily be solved in n^2 operations (or less if you use some maps), I think most of the problems are coming from the architecture.

The trigger should look something like:

```
trigger CheckDuplicateInsert on Customer__c(before insert,before update){

   if(Trigger.isInsert()){
       TriggerHandler.removeDuplicatesBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);

   } 

   if(Trigger.isUpdate()){
       TriggerHandler.removeDuplicatesBeforeUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.old);
   }

}
```

No other code is needed inside the trigger, notice also that you don't have Trigger.old before insert.

The Handler class will have the two methods, one for before insert, one for before update. The main idea to filter the duplicates in Trigger.New and to store "the last one in the list" is to create a map whose key is your unique "LastName+FirstName+Title". Then save in a list all the indexes of the customers that should be removed or marked as error in Trigger.new

```
public without sharing class TriggerHandler{
    ....

    Map <Strng, Customer__c> uidContactMap = new Map <String,Customer__c>();
    List <Integer> customersToBeRemoved = new List <Integer>();

    for(Integer i= 0; i< newCustomerList.size(); i++) {

         if(uidContactMap.get(c.LastName__c+c.FirstName__c+c.Title__c)!=null ){
            customersToBeRemoved.add(i);
            uidContactMap.put(c.LastName__c+c.FirstName__c+c.Title__c, c); 
         } else {
            uidContactMap.put(c.LastName__c+c.FirstName__c+c.Title__c, c);
         }
    }  

   //now in the map you have all the good values
   //in the List Integer you have the index of the contacts that have to be removed from
   //your initial list.
   //Sort the customersToBeRemoved list and cycle it backwards to remove elements from 
   //form the customer list


}
```

At the end of that for loop you'll have in your map the filtered values.

The best way of checking also the Customers that you already have in the database depends on how many customers do you expect to have. I would not use this procedure to check also customers in the database, but I'd use a SOQL query and introduce a formula field with your "LastName+FirstName+Title" key. The reason behind this is that if you have 100k contacts checking everyone against everyone may take some time (and may incur into governor limits). The class is without sharing because maybe different users can't upload the same Customer, without sharing is needed to have queris looking over all possible customers.